# How to subset for specific columns?

Tags: r, filtering, subset

I have two data frames. One is a complete set. The other only has the names of the columns whose values I want to extract. How do I create a miniature of the full set that only accounts for the columns I am interested in? The problem is that the second data frame with the columns I am interested in is not ordered in a way that matches the full set.

```
a1       a2       a3       ...



#I want to extract for example a17, a23, a15, etc. (names of columns are identical)
```

Comment: `DF[,c('a1','a17','a2')]` just place the names you want in the subset dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If `df1` is the dataframe name of the complete set and `df2` has the column names that you want to extract you can directly do :

```
new_df <- df1[, names(df2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    select(names(df2))
```